# Счастливые числа

Tags: c

Как можно посчитать расстояние до ближайшего счастливого числа, если вводится произвольное число. (счастливым числом называется шестизначное число, в котором сумма первых трёх цифр равна сумме последних трёх цифр)

Comment: Шестизначное число, в котором сумма первых трёх цифр равна сумме  последних трёх цифр.

Comment: А почему не покатит прямой перебор, кстати?

Comment: До ближайшего счастливого числа в какую сторону. в любую или скажем на увеличение ?

Comment: Где ваш код? Вы хоть пытались?

Comment: @VladD перебор каких чисел вы хотите сделать? "счастливых"?

Comment: Можно в любую сторону.

Comment: @AndreiKhotko: Перебор соседних чисел. ±1, ±2, ±3, ...

Comment: @VladD да, идея хороша, я пока лучше ничего не придумал

Comment: @VladD еще одна важная деталь: как мне кажется, у ближайшего "счастливого числа" первые три цифры будут такие же, как и у вводимого.

Comment: @AndreiKhotko: Вроде бы нет. Для числа 100999 ближайшее счастливое число, кажется, 101011.

Comment: Надо в обе стороны проверять. И что то мне подсказывает, что основа алгоритма - "разбрасывание" текущей разности сумм начиная с младшего разряда. в одну сторону это 100% возможно, в другую может потребоваться переход через 0, т.е. изменение старшей части на +-1 и "разбрасывание" от 000 или 999

Comment: @VladD для 100999 ближайшее 101002...

Comment: @AGS17: И правда :) Но всё равно первые цифры не те.

Comment: Поскольку проверять не более 2000 чисел (т. к. нужное число найдётся в той же тысяче), то можно тупо перебрать.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Поиск ближайшего счастливого числа, вариант на C#:

```
public class LuckyNumberFinder
{
    public int FindClosest(int num)
    {
        // Если вводимое число меньше первого счатсливого - вернуть первое счастливое
        if (num <= 100001)
        {
            return 100001;
        }
        // Если вводимое число больше последнего счатсливого - вернуть последнее счастливое
        if (num >= 999999)
        {
            return 999999;
        }

        // Если вводимое число уже счастливое - вернуть его же
        if (CheckIfLucky(num))
        {
            return num;
        }

        var less = num;
        var more = num;
        var lessIsLucky = false;
        var moreIsLucky = false;
        // Тут цикл плюсует и минусует значения к вводимому для поиска
        // Если значение меньшее или значение большее - счастливое - заканчиваем цикл
        while (!lessIsLucky && !moreIsLucky)
        {
            lessIsLucky = CheckIfLucky(--less);
            moreIsLucky = CheckIfLucky(++more);
        }

        // Проверяем меньшее ли значение счастливое и, если да возвращаем его, иначе большее значение
        return lessIsLucky ? less : more;
    }


    // Тут просто считаем сумму первых и последних цифр и чекаем, равны ли они
    private static bool CheckIfLucky(int num)
    {
        var leftDigitsSum = GetSumOfDigits(num / 1000);
        var rightDigitsSum = GetSumOfDigits(num % 1000);

        return leftDigitsSum == rightDigitsSum;
    }

    private static int GetSumOfDigits(int num)
    {
        var sum = 0;

        while (num != 0)
        {
            sum += num % 10;
            num = num / 10;
        }

        return sum;
    }
}
```

Естественно, этот алгоритм можно оптимизировать.

Соответственно, для того, чтобы узнать расстояние до ближайшего числа, надо вычесть из числа ближайшее счастливое число и привести по модулю:

```
var num = 100999;
var luckyNumberFinder = new LuckyNumberFinder();
var closestLucky = luckyNumberFinder.FindClosest(num);
var difference = Math.Abs(num - closestLucky);
```

[Проверить](https://dotnetfiddle.net/0l4Hvp)!

Comment: А можно на словах объяснить алгоритм?

Comment: @Tommy ваше рвение разобраться самому просто поражает меня. Добавил комментарии к коду.

Comment: Какое-то у вас сложное условие цикла :)

Comment: @VladD изначально у меня было два флага `lessIsLucky` и `moreIsLucky`, но меня напрягала неиспользуемая переменная и решил просто избавится от нее. Обновил ответ...

Comment: @AGS17: ТС вроде хотел чистый C, так что будем считать это псевдокодом :)

Comment: @VladD упс. Меня так завлекло слово "алгоритм", что я даже не посмотрел на язык... Сейчас попробую подправить...

Comment: Спасибо, в коде разобрался)

Answer (score 2):

Вариант на `C`:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdbool.h>


int get_sum_of_digits(int num)
{
  int sum = 0;

  while (num != 0)
  {
    sum += num % 10;
    num = num / 10;
  }

  return sum;
}

// Тут просто считаем сумму первых и последних цифр и чекаем, равны ли они
bool check_if_lucky(int num)
{
  int leftDigitsSum = get_sum_of_digits(num / 1000);
  int rightDigitsSum = get_sum_of_digits(num % 1000);

  return leftDigitsSum == rightDigitsSum;
}

int find_closest_lucky_number(int num)
{
  // Если вводимое число меньше первого счатсливого - вернуть первое счастливое
  if (num <= 100001)
  {
    return 100001;
  }
  // Если вводимое число больше последнего счатсливого - вернуть последнее счастливое
  if (num >= 999999)
  {
    return 999999;
  }

  // Если вводимое число уже счастливое - вернуть его же
  if (check_if_lucky(num))
  {
    return num;
  }

  int less = num;
  int more = num;
  bool lessIsLucky = false;
  bool moreIsLucky = false;
  // Тут цикл плюсует и минусует значения к вводимому для поиска
  // Если значение меньшее или значение большее - счастливое - заканчиваем цикл
  while (!lessIsLucky && !moreIsLucky)
  {
    lessIsLucky = check_if_lucky(--less);
    moreIsLucky = check_if_lucky(++more);
  }

  // Проверяем меньшее ли значение счастливое и, если да возвращаем его, иначе большее значение
  return lessIsLucky ? less : more;
}

int main() {
  int num = 100999;
  int closestLucky = find_closest_lucky_number(num);
  printf("%d", closestLucky);

  return 0;
}
```

[Тестить тут](http://jdoodle.com/a/3wU)!

Comment: Ага, вариант с делением и остатком мне нравится больше.